# How do I pass command line arguments to my Python manage.py shell script?

Tags: django, python-3.x, shell, authentication, command-line

I have a Python 3.7 / Django project using the auth module.  I want to write a script to create users, but I'm very confused about how to do it.  I have created this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import sys

firstarg=sys.argv[1]
secondarg=sys.argv[2]

user=User.objects.create_user(firstarg, password=secondarg)
user.is_superuser=False
user.is_staff=False
user.save()
```

I would liek to pass a username and password argument to this script.  I tried the below

```
localhost:dental davea$ source venv/bin/activate; python manage.py shell < create_users.py "user1" "password"
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dental/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
usage: manage.py shell [-h] [--no-startup] [-i {ipython,bpython,python}]
                       [-c COMMAND] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                       [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                       [--traceback] [--no-color]
manage.py shell: error: unrecognized arguments: user1 password
```

but you can see the error it results in.  How do I invoke my script from teh command line, while creating the virtual environment it shoudl be running in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) by creating a class called `Command` in the directory `<app>/management/commands/<your_cmd.py>`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Adds a user to django'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('username')
        parser.add_argument('password')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if User.objects.create_user(options['username'], password=options['password']):
            self.stdout.write("Successfully added user {}.".format(options['username']))
```

This allows you to call

```
python manage.py your_cmd <username> <password>
```

to create a new user.